# VB.net TCP Non-Blocking State

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, basic

I have code that sending string from client to server with TCP Connection.
But i dont know how to convert it to NonBlocking TCP State Connection.
i have try to put socket.Blocking = FALSE, but that code give me an error.

Socket Error Code: 10035

Exception Title: A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately

Heres my code for sending string from client to server.

Server Code :

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text

Module Module1
    Dim soket As Socket
    Sub Main()
        Try
            Dim alamatIP As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")
            Dim tcpListener As New TcpListener(alamatIP, 8000)
            'soket.Blocking = False - THIS WILL GIVE ME AN ERROR
            tcpListener.Start()

            System.Console.WriteLine("Server port 8000...")

            Dim myendpoint As IPEndPoint
            myendpoint = CType(tcpListener.LocalEndpoint, IPEndPoint)

            System.Console.WriteLine("IP : " + myendpoint.Address.ToString + " and port is " + myendpoint.Port.ToString)
            System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection !")

            soket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket()
            myendpoint = CType(soket.RemoteEndPoint(), IPEndPoint)

            System.Console.WriteLine("Receiving from " + myendpoint.Address.ToString())

            Dim bitData(100) As Byte
            Dim newString As String = ""
            Do
                Try
                    Dim size As Integer = soket.Receive(bitData)
                    newString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bitData)
                    Console.WriteLine(newString)
                    Array.Clear(bitData, 0, bitData.Length)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Console.Write(ex.ToString())
                End Try
            Loop While newString <> "exit"
            soket.Close()
            tcpListener.Stop()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error ..." + ex.ToString())
        End Try
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Client Code :

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Try
            Dim tcpClient As New TcpClient 'creating the client
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting....")
            tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8000) 'connecting the client the server
            'port is same as in the server
            Console.WriteLine("Connected")
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the string to be transmitted : ")

            Dim strMessage As String
            Dim stm As Stream
            Dim counter As Integer = 0

            Do

                stm = tcpClient.GetStream() 'getting the stream of the client
                Dim ascenc As New ASCIIEncoding
                strMessage = Console.ReadLine()
                Dim byteData() As Byte = ascenc.GetBytes(strMessage)
                Console.WriteLine("Transmitted ")
                stm.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length())

            Loop While strMessage <> "exit"

                    tcpClient.Close() 'closing the connection
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error..." + ex.StackTrace.ToString()) 'writing the exception into the console
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tired the local IP address for the server machine?

Comment: Why would you want to make it non-blocking? That would break your code pretty bad as it's designed to wait for the information. Have you heard of _asynchronous sockets_? ([**client**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-client-socket-example) and [**server**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example) example) Be aware that you must still place a 'wait' in the `Main` method so that it doesn't exit the application until you say it can do so.

Comment: is it hard to make it nonblocking socket? is there any references to make nonblocking tcp server.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question: _Why_ do you want to do this? I cannot think of a valid reason to set `Socket.Blocking = False` in a console application... Is it because you want to be able to connect multiple clients?

Comment: Either way, making it asynchronous is the best way to make it "non-blocking" (see the links I shared in my first comment). By making it asynchronous you will achieve _"non-blockingness"_, and it doesn't require you to use a loop to check for data all the time.

Comment: @VisualVincent I believe your comments would constitute a good answer.  On a separate note, non-blocking sockets are a part of Berkeley standard and are available on numerous platforms so they're worth learning, even through somewhat artificial exercise.

Comment: If you use non-blocking mode then two things can happen when you call Receive().  Either the TCP driver has data available and you will get it.  Or it doesn't and returns an error to indicate that it doesn't.  You'll get an exception accordingly.  So what you see happening is entirely normal.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 : While that is true I rather think that if you're learning .NET one should focus on learning about "asynchronousness", async/await and the TPL, since (at least parts of) those are rather recent technology of the framework, and there's a lot of focus on them these days.

Answer (score 1):

When you attempt to read from a non-blocking socket or write to it and the operation cannot be completed right now, then the socket is supposed to signal an error. In VB it means it is supposed to raise an exception. For example, this happens when your machine hasn't received any data but you try to `Read` something.

Before trying an operation on a non-blocking socket, call [`Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.select(v=vs.110).aspx) or `Poll` in order to make sure it is ready for the operation.